# "Find out my secret" Mystery Challenge TROPE Name

Tags: genre, tropes, mystery

I'm looking for the name of a trope or mystery subgenre. The antagonist has a secret and they challenge the main character to find it.

If I have the trope name, it will be much easier to research books with similar structures and themes.

Comment: Riddler? (and some words to allow the comment)

Comment: Riddler's not a bad idea. Are all Riddler's challenges generally riddles or are they broader than that?

Comment: Ehh, I honestly think this i too unspecific to get you a trope name. Nearly every kidnapping trope involves 'finding out' where the victim is hidden based on (unintended) clues in communication.... Every StarTrek episode with Q is a 'solve my riddle or devolve as a species'…. Zodiac Killer is 'solve my cypher before I kill again'… All of these function as a MacGuffin to keep the mystery plot going.

Comment: [Criminal Mind Games](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CriminalMindGames) is one related trope. Although it's not clear from your description if what you're looking for is necessarily criminal.

Comment: I think there's an intrinsic difference between being invited to investigate and an investigation motivated by a crime or a threat @wetcircuit. Here, the challenge is optional. It seems to be halfway between Riddler's threat and looking into something out of curiosity. Maybe this isn't a necessarily a trope, since it's hard to find examples.

Comment: Charlie and the Chocolate Factory…? I feel like any treasure hunt is functionally like what you're describing, some pirate hid treasure, there are clues...

Comment: I think the treasure hunt is probably the answer. A hunt doesn't necessarily have to have someone inviting people to investigate, but the prize itself is an implicit motivation. The story structure is largely the same. Do you want to add this as an answer @wetcircuit?

Comment: I guess Ready Player Me is this 'treasure hunt' plot…, not sure it's actually an established trope but with enough examples you could start to see common elements.